# Display image using php with <img src=""

Tags: php, html, image, printing

I have stupid problem with the html/php rules. I'm trying to show an image from an `apache` server with this code using a table:

```
<?php

    //code

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo ' 
            <tr>        
              <td> '.$row['x'].' </td>
              <td> '.$row['y'].' </td>
              <td> '.$row['z'].' </td>
              <td> '.$row['f'].' </td>
              <td> '.$row['g'].' </td>
              <td> '.$row['d'].' </td>
              <td><img src=\"<?php echo $url; ?>\"/></td>
            </tr>';

}

//code

?>
```

But obviusly the inner php script is considered as normal text and no run!

Comment: `<?php` has already opened and you are using echo inside another echo. Try thid: `<td><img src=\"$url\"/></td>`

Comment: You're already inside PHP `<?php echo $url; ?>` - 2nd one today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't echo large blocks of HTML in PHP like that.  Its bad practice. No, actually, its horrible practice.  Instead learn to open and close the PHP tag as needed, like:

```
<?php
//code..code...code...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>                        
  <tr>      
    <td> <?php echo $row['x']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['y']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['z']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['f']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['g']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['d']; ?> </td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
//code..code...code
?>
```

There are several benefits to this, including that its less likely to break syntax highlighting and your code is not defaced with as many `\"` all over the place.

Comment: I've always wondered : is the other way *only* better to read/edit for a human ?

Comment: Thank's a lor for you advice and your help :).

Answer (score 1):

You're already inside PHP - you shouldn't open another `<?php` scope:

```
  echo ' 
      <tr>      
      <td> '.$row['x'].' </td>
      <td> '.$row['y'].' </td>
      <td> '.$row['z'].' </td>
      <td> '.$row['f'].' </td>
      <td> '.$row['g'].' </td>
      <td> '.$row['d'].' </td>
      <td><img src="' .$url . '"/></td>
      </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                          echo ' 
                              <tr>      
                              <td> '.$row['x'].' </td>
                              <td> '.$row['y'].' </td>
                              <td> '.$row['z'].' </td>
                              <td> '.$row['f'].' </td>
                              <td> '.$row['g'].' </td>
                              <td> '.$row['d'].' </td>
                              <td><img src="'.$url.'"/></td>
                              </tr>';
}
?>
```

It just a problem in concatenation, you need just combine those strings, not set another 'echo script'.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply close the php section and put plain html, then reopen php when needed like this :

```
<?php
$test = array( "a test","also","a","test");
$itteraror = 0;
$url = "#";
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
while($itteraror<sizeof($test)) {
?>
            <tr>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?></td>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?> </td>
              <td> <?php echo $test[$itteraror] ; ?> </td>
              <td><img src="<?php echo $url ; ?>" alt="my image"></td>
            </tr>

<?php
$itteraror++;
}


?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i did make some modification to your code in order for it to be standalone for testing purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Just change this:

```
<td><img src=\"<?php echo $url; ?>\"/></td>
```

to:

```
<td><img src="' . $url .'"/></td>
```